# How to avoid to display '#'?

Tags: javascript

when I click:

```
<a href="#" onclick="plus();">+ 1 </a>
```

then in the address bar appears '#' in addition to URL ( example.com/index.php?id=1# ).

Is there a way to avoid that ?

Comment: Is there a reason you use a link for that? Why not a button or other element and style it accordingly? Don't abuse links...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add `return false`. It will prevent the default action.

```
<a href="#" onclick="plus(); return false;">+ 1</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

Or this:

```
<a href="javascript:plus();">+ 1 </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

use preventDefault(); instead of return false.

for the reasons explained here.
http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/